# Clipping/Masking Sub-Parts of SVG Linked Image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a massive `image` of a map embedded in an SVG, which is much larger than the browser window and centered on the screen.

```
<svg id='map' width='7192' height='3912' viewBox='0 0 7192 3912' version='1.1'>
  <image width='7192' height='3912' x='0' y='0' preserveAspectRatio='none'
    xlink:href='map.jpg' />
  <!-------------------->
  <!-- paths are here -->
  <!-------------------->
</svg>
```

There are two paths. One path outlines a building. The other path outlines a sub-region on the map.

The user can click on these paths, at which point that specific path will gradually be centered in the middle of the screen using a `transition`.

**Once the path is centered, what I would like to do is clip or mask everything outside of that path, so that the only visible part of the image/map is the path that was selected and centered.**

**Does anybody know how to do this?**

I've tried using `clipPath` natively in HTML and also applying it to the SVG in CSS, both of which don't seem to work. Either that or I'm doing something wrong.

[Here is a working demo of the project.](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/wRXopM?editors=1010)

**The building can be located near the top middle section of the map. The sub-region, which is easier to locate considering its size, is located in the bottom right hand corner of the map.** If you `mouseenter` them, the paths will `fill`. If you click on them, they will be centered on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-use the clip path content as a target area for pointer events if you combine sibling selectors with the right value for [`pointer-events`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty). Setting this property will both define when CSS pseudo-classes apply and which mouse events will be captured. Your centering code could be triggered by a `click` event.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.highlight').forEach(use => {
    use.addEventListener('click', e => {
        alert(use.id + " was clicked.");
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: fill;
}
image {
  pointer-events: none;
}
#h1:hover ~ image {
  clip-path: url(#clip1);
}
#h2:hover ~ image {
  clip-path: url(#clip2);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="331">
  <clipPath id="clip1">
    <rect id="path1" x="20" y="20" width="80" height="80" />
  </clipPath>
  <clipPath id="clip2">
    <circle id="path2" cx="400" cy="200" r="80" />
  </clipPath>
  <!-- use elements must be direct siblings preceding the image -->
  <use class="highlight" id="h1" xlink:href="#path1" />
  <use class="highlight" id="h2" xlink:href="#path2" />
  <image xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" width="500" height="331" />
</svg>
```

Comment: is there any way to make the background transparent? the part that is clipped/hidden, transparent?

Comment: i've changed my [CODEPEN demo](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/wRXopM?editors=1010) (click on one of the paths to see what i'm talking about), so you can see what's going on. i'd like the clipped sub-region to be in front of the purple stuff, **or at least appear to be,** but the issue is that it doesn't truly clip the sub-region, it just masks the rest of the image with a solid color??

Comment: also, it doesn't seem to want to work with a group of paths. i'm applying `map.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#'+pid+')')` in JS.

Comment: 1. you need to set the clip-path on the `<image>`, not the `<svg>`. 2. The `<clipPath>` content model is [restricted](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath). `<g>` is not allowed. Do you really need these as separate path elements? Otherwise, you could just concatenate the `d` attribute values to have only one path.

Comment: even though i'm applying it to map, it's working for the non-group path. also, i simply changed the `zIndex` to get it to the layer that i want. i'll try combining the paths right now

Comment: After studying your code again, the map is currently behind the `.blackout` group, that is why it disappears. I think you have conceptual problem there. You use the "purple stuff" to mask the map with a solid color, moving from the outside in. But when the movement stops, you want the `.blackout` group to be behind what is still visible of the map after clipping. If I descibe your problem right, that would warrant a new question.

Comment: i worked it out already. like i said before, i simply changed the `zIndex` to sandwich the sub-region path in front of the purple, but still behind the text.

Comment: this whole thing created a new "issue". i realized that what i really want to do is is "preserve" the background; in other words, i want to make the part that is clipped and hidden remain visible, and instead simply separate the part that is clipped and hidden from the part that is still visible, so that when the purple stuff grows the part that is clipped is still visible **until** the purple stuff reaches the sub-region. does that make sense? i'll change my demo again, so that it's up-to-date.

Comment: It's what I suspected. One hint: think of the purple region as a solid filled rectangle that is behind the map, and that is revealed as the map is clipped to a shrinking rectangle, until that disappears behind the path part of the clipPath. Quote spec: "When the ‘clipPath’ element contains multiple child elements, the silhouettes of the child elements are logically OR'd together to create a single silhouette". IF that doesn't help you, ask a follow-up question.

Comment: [here is the question i just created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101984/separate-clipped-area-from-non-clipped-area) **thanks again for all of your help!! i really appreciate it**